# Airflow graph/tree view auto-refresh?

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

In the Apache Airflow UI, the timer at the top auto-updates:

[image]

But to follow the progress of a specific DAG-run, I have to keep clicking the refresh button:

[image]

Does anyone know if there is a way to configure the airflow ui to auto-update the tree view to watch the progress of a dag in real time?

(It would also be nice to have the same feature for the graph view.)

Comment: soon :)  https://twitter.com/kaxil/status/1316725687168966657?s=20
I am not sure about the treeview though.

Answer (score 2):

This feature is available for [Graph View](http://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/ui.html#graph-view) since Airflow 2.0.0

[image]

And for Tree View since Airflow 2.1.0:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

No feature like this in Airflow for now, but you can just use some Chrome auto-refresh plugin.

I find [Page Refresh](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-refresh/hmooaemjmediafeacjplpbpenjnpcneg?hl=en) very useful.